# What should be the proper thing to do with this answer?

Tags: discussion

I was going through the first post review queue and came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29753359/4342498) answer to [“elseif” syntax in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4005614/elseif-syntax-in-javascript). I marked it as "no action needed", but after I reviewed some more questions I just couldn't justify that response and it is bothering me. I haven't come across an answer like this and I am unsure what to do with it.

Comment: You can down vote, flag, comment or edit if there's enough substance worth making into a real answer.

Comment: In future, please post the answer under discussion as a quotation within your question, to preserve it, and also for clarity. When we follow your link now, only a few hours later, apparently the answer has been deleted, and we can only scratch our heads and guess at what it might have said, and in what tone and language.

Comment: @smci will do.  I forgot the link would break if the post was removed.  If there is a mod or someone with enough rep that would be willing to add the text of the deleted answer to this post it would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm surprised by the amount of up votes that such a poor question has. Could it be closed as a syntactical error?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The user who posted that answer ([jolsen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4811300/jolsen)) is trying to reply to a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4005614/elseif-syntax-in-javascript/29753359#comment4292106_4005623) on the accepted answer, and the comment was also misunderstood by the user. It says:

> When people ask questions like this.. I think it shows a fundamental misunderstanding. With `if` and `else` there really is no need of `elseif`. –  [Mark](https://stackoverflow.com/users/65387/mark)

What Mark is trying to say, is that, in a language which has an `if` statement, and an `else` statement, you can build up an `else if` condition without the need of a different (and useless) statement such as `elseif`. Jolsen didn't get the comment and attempted to reply arguing that:

> Else if statements are akin to using "switch", however it will allow for more elaborate comparisons. Switch, of course, allows for very simple comparisons only. So yes, there's definitely good reasons for using else if. [...]

Yes it should have been worded better, but the point is that Mark wasn't actually saying that there is no good reason to use `else if`: he was talking about the `elseif` statement (that little space makes the difference :P).

---

### Conclusion?

**[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29753359/3889449) should be deleted as an attempt to reply to another comment in a different post**, selecting the relative option: "this is commentary on another post, not an answer". Plus, jolsen is also saying that by their own: *"I don't get to add comments yet [...]"*.

Comment: And this is _why_ low-rep users don't get to add comments. It's because they almost universally haven't learnt how the site works yet. They're supposed to _watch_ and _learn_ before commenting, not blast in like a bull in a china shop posting their discussion points wherever the system will technically let them. :(

Comment: @LightningRacisinObrit But, bulls are *graceful* there  http://www.discovery.com/tv-shows/mythbusters/videos/the-buster-awards-bull-in-a-china-shop/    ;)